# Preimage of a regular curve

Tags: differential-geometry

My reference book for definitions of regular curve and regular surface is Do Carmo's book on differential geometry.

Let $C$ be regular plane curve. Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ be a smooth map, and assume that $Df(p)$ has rank 2 for all $p\in S:=f^{-1}(C)$.  I want to prve that $S$ is a regular surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

For this work, I describe $C$ as a level set locally and conside the composed map. For finishing the proof, I do not know exactly what I do. How is the details?